# What is the fastest way to save data in SQL Server using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am currently working on a small .NET app in C#, that fetches data through some web service.

The data is represented in objects, so it would have been logical to store the data in a document based database, but there is a demand to use SQL Server.

So what might be the fastest way to insert many thousands, perhaps millions of rows into a database.

I an open to any framework, that might could support that, but I haven't been able to find any benchmarking on this e.g. on Entity Framework.

To iterate over the data an do an insert per row is simply to slow, then it would be quicker to dump the data in a file, and then do a bulk import using SSIS, but for this scenario I would rather avoid that, and keep all logic in the C# app.

Comment: Just because the data is represented in objects does not mean that a document based database is preferable.  Document based databases are more geared towards data that doesn't necessarily line up neatly into columns and rows.  If your data is heavily structured (even if represented as objects in your app) then a traditional database is best.  You might want to read the following:  http://www.dbta.com/Articles/Editorial/Trends-and-Applications/SQL-or-NoSQL-How-to-Choose-the-Right-Database-for-Your-Application-71240.aspx

Comment: http://itzonesl.blogspot.com/2012/12/import-excel-data-into-sql-server-table.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to use the `SqlBulkCopy` class. It is quite efficient for large data.

Comment: Thank you it seems like this is what I am looking for.